# How to connect to Oracle ubuntu instance using RDP protocol via Windows or Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, windows, xrdp, rdp

I want to run selenium on my ubuntu server (oraclecloud) on instance type VM.Standard.A1.Flex. I did try to install RDP and connect with RDP client but connection is failing.

I followed multiple [blogs](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-xrdp-on-ubuntu-20-04/) on internet to install and connect using RDP but it is not working. I am getting following error while I am tring to make a connection.

[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BiOz.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT 6 -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 3389 -j ACCEPT
sudo netfilter-persistent save
sudo adduser (username)
```

The last command will prompt you for a password twice. After entering the password, run:

```
sudo usermod -G xrdp (username)
sudo reboot
```

If the username you created does not work for login, just use the one you are currently using for `ssh`.